# jquery variable names within quotes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to make a selection in a select control using jquery. The value searched for is a jquery variable. I found this solution(which works) here at stackoverflow.

```
$("#selectbox option[value = '2011/1']").prop('selected', true);
```

but I want to use a variable in the single quotes to search for

```
var target = '2011/1';

$("#selectbox option[value = 'target']").prop('selected', true);
```

I have tried many combinations with and without the single quotes with no success. So what is the solution?

Comment: It's a string, you build a string like normal.

Answer (score 3):

You can just concatenate the string with a variable:

```
$("#selectbox option[value = '"+target+"']").prop('selected', true);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can concatenate the variable value, like so:

```
$("#selectbox option[value ='" + target + "']").prop('selected', true);
```

Answer (score 0):

In ES6 you can use [Template strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/template_strings)

```
$(`#selectbox option[value = '${target}']`)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try escaping character `"/"` within `target` variable with `\\`

```js
var target = "2011\\/1";

$("#selectbox option[value=" + target + "]").prop('selected', true);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<select id="selectbox">
  <option value="2010/1">2010/1</option>
 <option value="2011/1">2011/1</option>
</select>
```